# Different behaviour between ion-tab tab attribute and ion-fab routerLink

Tags: ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I have an ionic tab page containing event specific information to display.
Routing is set up so that you are routed to a specific event's tab page

tabs.page.html

```
<ion-tabs>
    <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom" mode="md">
        <ion-tab-button tab="token">
            <ion-icon src="/assets/svg/ticket-star.svg"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>Tokens</ion-label>
        </ion-tab-button>

        <ion-tab-button tab="transactions">
            <ion-icon src="/assets/svg/empty-wallet-change.svg"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>Transactions</ion-label>
        </ion-tab-button>

        <div class="centerd-btn"></div>

        <ion-tab-button tab="swipe">
            <ion-icon src="/assets/svg/people.svg"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>Swipe</ion-label>
        </ion-tab-button>

        <ion-tab-button tab="buy">
            <ion-icon src="/assets/svg/card.svg"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>Buy</ion-label>
        </ion-tab-button>

        <ion-tab-button tab="user" hidden>
        </ion-tab-button>

        <ion-tab-button tab="notifications" hidden>
        </ion-tab-button>

        <ion-tab-button tab="help" hidden>
        </ion-tab-button>

    </ion-tab-bar>
    <ion-fab vertical="bottom" horizontal="center" slot="fixed">
        <ion-fab-button routerLink="scan" routerLinkActive="active-tab" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}">
            <ion-icon src="/assets/svg/qr-scan.svg"></ion-icon>
        </ion-fab-button>
        <ion-label>Scan at bar</ion-label>
    </ion-fab>
</ion-tabs>
```

tabs-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { TabsPage } from './tabs.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':eventId',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'home',
        loadChildren: () => import('../home/home.module').then(m => m.HomePageModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'token',
        loadChildren: () => import('../token/token.module').then(m => m.TokenPageModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'transactions',
        loadChildren: () => import('../transactions/transactions.module').then(m => m.TransactionsPageModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'swipe',
        loadChildren: () => import('../swipe/swipe.module').then(m => m.SwipePageModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'buy',
        loadChildren: () => import('../buy/buy.module').then(m => m.BuyPageModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'scan',
        loadChildren: () => import('../scan/scan.module').then(m => m.ScanPageModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'notifications',
        loadChildren: () => import('../notifications/notifications.module').then(m => m.NotificationsPageModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'help',
        loadChildren: () => import('../help/help.module').then(m => m.HelpPageModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'user',
        loadChildren: () => import('../user/user.module').then(m => m.UserPageModule)
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/event/swipedrinks/home',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: TabsPage
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class TabsPageRoutingModule {}
```

All works fine except for this `<ion-fab>` element's routing.
I can click it the first time and the app is routed correctly to for example `/event/A4OUJTpgYfeNEF6e5k4v/scan` but after clicking on another tab element you can't go back to the scan part.

I don't have any console errors so I don't really know where to start.

I guess Ionic is handling the `tab` attribute not the same as `routerLink` attribute in the `ion-fab` element but what is the alternative then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi it seems like there is some issue in sol ionic faced same issue at side nav resolved issue by using (click)="navController.naviagteForward('event/scan')" and in constructor constructor(public navController:NavController)

Comment: I need the eventId in the parameter, event/scan has no route so it should be like /event/A4OUJTpgYfeNEF6e5k4v/scan. But problem then is that I can't grab this eventId in the tabs.page.ts file

Comment: Got it from the activeRoute in the tabs.page.ts file

Comment: As eventid mentioned for tabs page the route should be like tabs/:eventid/scan I don't know where you get event route from and in the tabs.page.ts constructor(private actRoute: ActivatedRoute) { this.actRoute.params.subscribe(r=>{ this.id=r["eventId"]; }) } and you can't use snapshot as when u revisit constructor won't be called

Comment: I use snapshot in ionViewWillEnter, so it's called upon revisit
ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.routeId = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.eventId;
  }

Comment: did you actuvally check route you specified i think you have to pass like tabs/eventid/scan and not event/eventid/scan  can you please check or share the more code or error you got? and it should work when you do that in ionViewWillEnter

Comment: Oh but it works like a charm :) I just didn't know how t o grab the parameter but with your hint with the navController all issues are solved!

Comment: welcome i will be very happy if you you donate 50 reputation i am running low please!